# MVC 3 data annotations turn off validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have Entity set and i create partial class

```
[Bind(Include = "ID,Note,Spec,Retired")]
  [MetadataType(typeof(SomeClass))]
  public partial class Users
  {
  }
```

and in this class I have some data annotations

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ReqField")]
    [Display(Name = "Note")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources.Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "LenghtNotLonger255")]
    public string Note
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
```

In View

```
<div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Spec)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Spec)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Note)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Note)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)
</div>
```

And everything works fine. But on edit I don't want to have validation on this Note field. How can I Do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard thing here is to do is to create a separate model (ViewModel) for that scenario without validation